# English to French, French to English translator web app

Tags: javascript, html

The goal of this task is to write a translator web app using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. The aim is to switch the following phrases from English to French and vice versa. I've declared two objects called *englishToFrench* and *frenchToEnglish* and a global variable called sourceText used in the function below. The first function is supposed to convert English to French and vice versa. The second function is to bring whatever the user clicks to be displayed into the textbox. However this won't execute and I have no idea why. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <head lang="en">
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
      <script type="application/javascript" src="js/client.js"></script>
     <title>A simple tranlation app</title>
   </head>
  <body>
  <h1>A simple tranlation app</h1>
  <div>
    <textarea id="sourceText"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div>
    <label for="translation">Choose:</label>
    <select id="translation" name="translation">
        <option value="engToFrench">English to French</option>
        <option value="frenchToEng">French to English</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <textarea id="targetText" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="translateBtn" type="button">Translate</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>



var englishToFrench = {
        'He': 'il',
        'throws': 'jete',
        'the': 'la',
        'ball': 'balle',
        'I': 'je',
        'ride': 'monte',
        'my': 'mon',
        'bicycle': 'velo',
        'to': 'au',
        'work': 'travail',
        'Peter': 'Pierre',
        'likes': 'aime',
        'computer': 'programmation',
        'programming': 'informatique',
        'John': 'Jean',
        'plays': 'joue',
        'hockey': 'au hockey',
        'She': 'elle',
        'eats': 'mange',
        'a lot': 'beaucoup',
        'of': 'de',
        'chicken': 'poulet',

    }
    var frenchToEnglish = {
        'il': 'He',
        'jete': 'throws',
        'la': 'the',
        'balle': 'ball',
        'je': 'I',
        'monte': 'ride',
        'mon': 'my',
        'velo': 'bicycle',
        'au': 'to',
        'travail': 'work',
        'Pierre': 'Peter',
        'aime': 'likes',
        'programmation': 'computer',
        'informatique': 'programming',
        'Jean': 'John',
        'joue': 'plays',
        'au hockey': 'hockey',
        'elle': 'She',
        'mange': 'eats',
        'beaucoup': 'a lot',
        'de': 'of',
        'poulet': 'chicken',


    }

}

var sourceText;

var translateText = function (response){
    if(sourceText === englishToFrench || sourceText === frenchToEnglish){
        document.getElementById('translation').value;


    }
}


var translateBtnClickHandler = function() {
var sourceText = document.getElementById('sourceText').value;
var translation = document.getElementById('translation').value;
alert('translate was clicked; src text: ' + sourceText + ' translation: ' + translation);

    };

 window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('translateBtn').onclick = translateBtnClickHandler;
    };
```

Comment: Could you mark your question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript was not inside a `<script></script>`. You also had a superfluous curly bracket.

[image: developer tools with console in Firefox]

Next time you can open the [developer tools](http://devtoolsecrets.com/) in your browser to find syntax errors like these (see screenshot).

Below is your fixed code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <script type="application/javascript" src="js/client.js"></script>
  <title>A simple tranlation app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>A simple tranlation app</h1>
  <div>
    <textarea id="sourceText"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="translation">Choose:</label>
    <select id="translation" name="translation">
      <option value="engToFrench">English to French</option>
      <option value="frenchToEng">French to English</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="targetText" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="translateBtn" type="button">Translate</button>
  </div>
  <div id="alert"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var englishToFrench = {
      'He': 'il',
      'throws': 'jete',
      'the': 'la',
      'ball': 'balle',
      'I': 'je',
      'ride': 'monte',
      'my': 'mon',
      'bicycle': 'velo',
      'to': 'au',
      'work': 'travail',
      'Peter': 'Pierre',
      'likes': 'aime',
      'computer': 'programmation',
      'programming': 'informatique',
      'John': 'Jean',
      'plays': 'joue',
      'hockey': 'au hockey',
      'She': 'elle',
      'eats': 'mange',
      'a lot': 'beaucoup',
      'of': 'de',
      'chicken': 'poulet',

    }
    var frenchToEnglish = {
      'il': 'He',
      'jete': 'throws',
      'la': 'the',
      'balle': 'ball',
      'je': 'I',
      'monte': 'ride',
      'mon': 'my',
      'velo': 'bicycle',
      'au': 'to',
      'travail': 'work',
      'Pierre': 'Peter',
      'aime': 'likes',
      'programmation': 'computer',
      'informatique': 'programming',
      'Jean': 'John',
      'joue': 'plays',
      'au hockey': 'hockey',
      'elle': 'She',
      'mange': 'eats',
      'beaucoup': 'a lot',
      'de': 'of',
      'poulet': 'chicken',


    }


    var sourceText;

    var translateText = function(response) {
      if (sourceText === englishToFrench || sourceText === frenchToEnglish) {
        document.getElementById('translation').value;


      }
    }


    var translateBtnClickHandler = function() {
      var sourceText = document.getElementById('sourceText').value;
      var translation = document.getElementById('translation').value;
      document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = 'translate was clicked; src text: ' + sourceText + ' translation: ' + translation;

    };

    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('translateBtn').onclick = translateBtnClickHandler;
    };
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `alert` doesn't work and is blocked. Use `console.log` instead :) Or print it into the textarea.

Comment: I get `Ignored call to 'alert()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.` at js:107

Comment: I think that's due to your snippet thing, the code on its own would work, but it doesn't here in the snippet for some reason.

Comment: @Vadorequest replaced the alert with console.log but the button still will not execute. Any ideas?

Comment: Now the snippet works indeed, the text is added at the bottom.

Comment: @DanielTavares Just open your Console (f12) and see if anything is added there when you click on the button.

Comment: @Vadorequest so in the snippet code, I typed 'he' in english and I clicked on the translate button, and nothing comes up period, however outside the textbox I get your "translate was clicked; src text: he translation: to engToFrench. "src text". Sorry for being dense but I'm trying to get the translated french word of he to appear into the textbox. Thank you.

Comment: I've made my own answer because I needed to change the source code. Thanks to @nylki, I didn't know about that snippet thing!

Comment: @Vadorequest you are welcome. +1 for your educational answer with ToDo's instead of plain answering, I like that!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so based on the other answer, I've made this quick thing.

It's not completed yet and I won't do it. You made some serious beginner mistakes so I guess you're just getting started with JS programming :)

What I did was to fix a few mistakes (conditions, variables...) and I left some TODO for you to fill. Now the output is displayed in the target area as you wanted. But the text is not translated, you'll need to do that part.

It's not really complicated, you're basically translating word-by-word, so you just need to do the following:

1. Take the input
2. Split it by space to get an array of strings.
3. Translate each word one by one according to the selected translation type.
4. Display the fully translated result in the textarea. (you'll need to convert the array back to a string)

Have fun, programming's fun, but you get to do things yourself to fully understand them! ;)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/client.js"></script>
    <title>A simple tranlation app</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>A simple tranlation app</h1>
    <div>
        <textarea id="sourceText"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="translation">Choose:</label>
        <select id="translation" name="translation">
            <option value="englishToFrench">English to French</option>
            <option value="frenchToEnglish">French to English</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="targetText" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="translateBtn" type="button">Translate</button>
    </div>
    <div id="alert"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var englishToFrench = {
            'He': 'il',
            'throws': 'jete',
            'the': 'la',
            'ball': 'balle',
            'I': 'je',
            'ride': 'monte',
            'my': 'mon',
            'bicycle': 'velo',
            'to': 'au',
            'work': 'travail',
            'Peter': 'Pierre',
            'likes': 'aime',
            'computer': 'programmation',
            'programming': 'informatique',
            'John': 'Jean',
            'plays': 'joue',
            'hockey': 'au hockey',
            'She': 'elle',
            'eats': 'mange',
            'a lot': 'beaucoup',
            'of': 'de',
            'chicken': 'poulet',

        };
        var frenchToEnglish = {
            'il': 'He',
            'jete': 'throws',
            'la': 'the',
            'balle': 'ball',
            'je': 'I',
            'monte': 'ride',
            'mon': 'my',
            'velo': 'bicycle',
            'au': 'to',
            'travail': 'work',
            'Pierre': 'Peter',
            'aime': 'likes',
            'programmation': 'computer',
            'informatique': 'programming',
            'Jean': 'John',
            'joue': 'plays',
            'au hockey': 'hockey',
            'elle': 'She',
            'mange': 'eats',
            'beaucoup': 'a lot',
            'de': 'of',
            'poulet': 'chicken',

        };

        var translateText = function() {
            var translationType = document.getElementById('translation').value;

            if (translationType === 'englishToFrench') {
                console.log('translation used: English to French');
                // TODO You need to translate the input, the best is to write a function that does the work. It should split the whole input by spaces to get all the words one by one and translate them one by one. But that's for you to do ;) Have fun!
                return 'TODO see your code (1)';
            }else if(translationType === 'frenchToEnglish'){
                console.log('translation used: French to English');
                return 'TODO see your code (2)';
            }else{
                return "No valid translation selected.";
            }
        };


        var translateBtnClickHandler = function() {
            var sourceText = document.getElementById('sourceText').value;

            // Copy the translation in the target area.
            document.getElementById('targetText').value = translateText();

        };

        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById('translateBtn').onclick = translateBtnClickHandler;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```